# Tensorflow hub module taking long time for embedding single sentence

Tags: tensorflow

I am using universal sentence encoder from tensorflow hub to encode sentence into embedding.

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow as tf

module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/1?tf-hub-format=compressed"

def get_emb(text):
    embed = hub.Module(module_url)
    similarity_input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=(None))
    similarity_message_encodings = embed(similarity_input_placeholder)
    with tf.Session() as session:
            session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            session.run(tf.tables_initializer())
            message_embeddings_ = session.run(similarity_message_encodings, feed_dict={similarity_input_placeholder: text})
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    return message_embeddings_
```

Now the problem is each time I call the function the time is taking is about 10 seconds which is very high. Is there a way to save the model or something and do it instantly. This will be used in restful service where the response should be near instant

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the model like this:

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4"
model = hub.load(module_url)
print ("module %s loaded" % module_url)
def embed(input):
    return model(input)
```

And then:

```
embed(["This is a nice string!"])
```

Which would return:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 512), dtype=float32, numpy= array([[ 8.84598400e-03, ... , 1.89793427e-02]], dtype=float32)>
```

That is the 512 dimension vector, but you can choose the one you need between all the encoders here: https://tfhub.dev/

Hope it helps.